# what's wrong with this code?? http://www.spoj.pl/problems/ARRAYSUB/

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
typedef struct node
{
    long int n;
    struct node *l,*r;
}node;
typedef node * tree;
tree maknod(long int d)
{
    tree t;
    t=(tree)malloc(sizeof(tree));
    t->n=d;
    t->l=t->r=NULL;
    return t;
}

tree ins(tree t,long int d)
{
    if(t==NULL)
    return maknod(d);
    else if(t->n > d)
    t->l=ins(t->l,d);
    else 
    t->r=ins(t->r,d);
    return t;
}
long int findmax(tree t)
{
    if(t->r==NULL)
    return (t->n);
    findmax(t->r);
}
tree del(tree t,long int d)
{
    if(t!=NULL)
    {
    if(t->n==d)
    {
        if(t->l==NULL && t->r==NULL)
        return NULL;
        if(t->l==NULL)
        return t->r;
        if(t->r==NULL)
        return t->l;
        t->n=findmax(t->l);
        t->l=del(t->l,t->n);
    }
    if(t->n>d)
    t->l=del(t->l,d);
    if(t->n<d)
    t->r=del(t->r,d);
}
return t;
}
long int print(tree t)
{
    if(t->r==NULL)
    return t->n;
    print(t->r);
}
int main()
{
long int num,k,i;
tree t=NULL;
scanf("%ld ",&num);
long int a[num];
for(i=0;i<num;i++)
scanf("%ld",&a[i]);
scanf("%ld",&k);
for(i=0;i<k;i++)
{
    t=ins(t,a[i]);
}
for(i=0;i<=num-k;i++)
{
if(i<num-k)
{
printf("%ld",print(t));
printf(" ");
}
else
printf("%ld",print(t));
t=del(t,a[i]);
ins(t,a[i+k]);
}
return 0;
}
```

> > http://ideone.com/ZA3Xb
> >     in spoj its running for five test cases and in sixth one its comin as segmentation fault..
> >     given num is no of elements in array then a[] contains num elements.. k is the size of sub array.. we have to print max element in each sub array of size k in a[].

Comment: Please indent your code. It makes it human-readable...

Comment: Nice use of ideone.com, but your question is lacking substance.  You may find that providing more background info and/or describing your debugging attempts may yield more assistance.

Answer (score 3):

```
tree t = malloc( sizeof( tree ));
```

is not correct.  This is one reason that obfuscating typedef's are a bad idea.
A good idiom is:

```
node *t;
t = malloc( sizeof *t )
```

If you want to keep the typedef, you need something like

t = malloc( sizeof( node )).

There are probably other problems in the code...

Comment: +1, another reason why typedefing object pointers types is bad

Comment: No. Another reason why mallocing sizeof(type) is bad and should be written instead as `pointer = malloc(sizeof(*pointer));`

Comment: some test cases only are getting segmentattion fault in spoj just look into tat ques...